# Evaluating scripts in an ajax response

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, jquery

I have the following code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: urlData,
    data: { OwnerId: ownerIdData, Text: textData },
    success: function (data) {
        $('#post-container').prepend(data);
    },
    error: function () {
    }
});
```

Now I want to `eval` the scripts contained in the variable data in the success function.
How I do that ? 
Thanks in advance.

EDIT

I have the following form:

```
<form class="new-post-form">

    <textarea id="post-creation-text-input" name="Text" rows="10"> Write something ... </textarea>
    <input type="hidden" value="@Model.OwnerId" id="post-creation-id-input"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Post" id="post-creation-submit-input" />


    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#post-creation-submit-input').click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var textData = $('#post-creation-text-input').val();
            var ownerIdData = $('#post-creation-id-input').val();
            var urlData = '@Url.Action("Create", "Posts")';


            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: urlData,
                data: { OwnerId: ownerIdData, Text: textData },
                success: function (data) {

                    $('#post-container').prepend(data);

                    });
                },
                error: function () {
                }
            });

        });
    </script>

</form>
```

Now the ajax response is the following view:

```
@using Facebook.Presentation.Web.Utils
@model Facebook.Presentation.Web.ViewModels.Posts.PostViewModel



<div class="post" id ="last-post">
    <h3>@Html.UserName(Model.Author)</h3>
    <br/>
    <div>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Text)
    </div>
    <br/>
    @{
        Html.RenderPartial("_CommentsPartial", Model.Comments, new ViewDataDictionary { { "ActionName", "Comment" }, { "ControllerName", "Posts" } });
    }  
</div>
```

This response also contains scripts that must be evaluated.

Thanks again.

Comment: Please include an example of the script you want to eval in your question.  It's unclear what you're trying to do.

Comment: Gut reaction to any question about how to use `eval` is "Don't use eval". What is it you're trying to do? I'm sure there's a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `jQuery.getScript()` function. Documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/